# tomcat memory calculation different

Tags: memory, jvm

we have two systems on which tomcat is configured with Xmx=8g Xms=8g. A piece of Java code reads the memory (I'm no developer, but it is the same on both servers), and both report different memory, one says
Max memory 8009 MByte and the other
Max memory 8188 MByte
where could the difference come from?

Comment: What is the code that "*reads the memory"*?

Comment: Are the two systems meant to be identical? Same tomcat installation, same JVM? If not can you include details about the difference in between the two servers?

Comment: we have no access to the code... it's a checkpage that tells some status of the application, though it's the same on both servers. Also servers *should* be identical, though it's possible that i.e. some env variable could be different, that's why I'm looking for a hint where to look at. tomcat and JVM are identical

Comment: So, *some unknown code* that you don't have access to, prints some random numbers, and you ask us why it does that?

Comment: not quite... I'm asking why identical code puts out different number on different servers ;) It shouldn't be code specific, but environment. Like some env that tells JVM to calculate in kb or in Mb. And the numbers are not random it reads the available heap space (Xmx)

Comment: *"the numbers are not random it reads the available heap space"* - There are many ways to query available heap space, and some of them indeed can produce almost random results. That's why I'm asking what exactly the code does.